# access properties of referenced objects in golang template (Google app engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, templates, go, data-modeling, google-cloud-datastore

I have a data model `Sections:`

```
type Sections struct{
    SectionName     string
    IsFather        bool
    ParentSection   *datastore.Key
}
```

I pass sections as value to golang template and I want to get `ParentSection` name `ParentSection.SectionName` so how can I do this from template like `jinja2` in python `{{ParentSection.get().SectionName}}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package is not "appengine-aware", it does not know about the GAE platform, and it does not support automatic resolution of such references.

By design philosophy, templates should not contain complex logic. If something is (or looks) too complex in templates, it should be implemented in functions. And you may register your custom functions with the [`Template.Funcs()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Funcs) method which you can call from templates.

For your use case I recommend the following custom function which loads a `Sections` by its key:

```
func loadSections(ctx appengine.Context, k *datastore.Key) (*Sections, error) {
    s := Sections{}
    err := datastore.Get(ctx, k, &s)
    return &s, err
}
```

Note that you need the `Context` for loading entities from the Datastore, so you have to make it available too in the template params. So your template params may look like this:

```
ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)

m := map[string]interface{}{
    "Sections": s, // A previously loaded Sections
    "Ctx":      ctx,
}
```

And by registering and using this function, you can get what you want:

```
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
        "loadSections": loadSections,
    }).Parse(`my section name: {{.Sections.SectionName}},
parent section name: {{(loadSections .Ctx .Sections.ParentSection).SectionName}}`))

    t.Execute(w, m)
```

Now let's say you have a parent `Sections` whose name is `"parSecName"`, and you have a child `Sections` whose name is `"childSecName"`, and child's `ParentSection` points to the parent's `Sections`. Executing the above template you'll see this result:

```
my section name: childSecName,
parent section name: parSecName
```

### Complete example

See this complete working example. Note: it is for demonstration purposes only, it is not optimized for production.

It registers the `/put` path to insert 2 `Sections`. And you may use any other path to execute the template. So test it like this:

First insert 2 `Sections`:

```
http://localhost:8080/put
```

Then execute and view template result:

```
http://localhost:8080/view
```

Complete runnable code:

```
// +build appengine

package gplay

import (
    "appengine"
    "appengine/datastore"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/put", puthandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/", myhandler)
}

func myhandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)

    s := Sections{}
    if err := datastore.Get(ctx, datastore.NewKey(ctx, "Sections", "", 2, nil), &s); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    m := map[string]interface{}{
        "Sections": s,
        "Ctx":      ctx,
    }

        t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
            "loadSections": loadSections,
        }).Parse(`my section name: {{.Sections.SectionName}},
    parent section name: {{(loadSections .Ctx .Sections.ParentSection).SectionName}}`))

        t.Execute(w, m)
}

    func loadSections(ctx appengine.Context, k *datastore.Key) (*Sections, error) {
        s := Sections{}
        err := datastore.Get(ctx, k, &s)
        return &s, err
    }

func puthandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)

    s := Sections{"parSecName", false, nil}

    var k *datastore.Key
    var err error
    if k, err = datastore.Put(ctx, datastore.NewKey(ctx, "Sections", "", 1, nil), &s); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    s.SectionName = "childSecName"
    s.ParentSection = k
    if _, err = datastore.Put(ctx, datastore.NewKey(ctx, "Sections", "", 2, nil), &s); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

type Sections struct {
    SectionName   string
    IsFather      bool
    ParentSection *datastore.Key
}
```

### Some notes

This child-parent relation can be modeled with the `Key` itself as a key may optionally contain a parent `Key`.

If you don't want to "store" the parent Key in the entity's key itself, it may also be enough to just store either the key's name or the key's ID (depending on what you use), as from that the key can be constructed.